# How to deserialize from BSON to basic struct - ANSI C

Tags: c, mongodb, bson

I am building an app that uses mongodb to store some data. My problem is that when I want to deserialize the BSON's that I get from mongo, I get some warnings from valgrind, so I think that I may be doing something wrong when "deserializing"..

The code:

I made a function that receives a bson_t and returns my own struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char id[25];
    char *name;
    char *parentId;
} dir_t;

dir_t* dir_getDirFromBSON(const bson_t *doc) {
    bson_iter_t iter;
    const bson_value_t *value;
    const char *key;
    dir_t *dir = dir_create();

    if (bson_iter_init(&iter, doc)) {
        while (bson_iter_next(&iter)) {
            key = bson_iter_key(&iter);
            value = bson_iter_value(&iter);

            if (strcmp(key, "_id") == 0) {
                strcpy(dir->id, value->value.v_utf8.str);
            } else if (strcmp(key, "name") == 0) {
                strcpy(dir->name, value->value.v_utf8.str);
            } else if (strcmp(key, "parentId") == 0) {
                strcpy(dir->parentId, value->value.v_utf8.str);
            }


        }
    }

    return dir;
}

dir_t* dir_create() {
    dir_t* dir = malloc(sizeof(dir_t));
    dir->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 512);
    dir->parentId = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
    return dir;
}
```

I made the ID to be a string in the db, so there is no problem with that. But valgrind is throwing me lots of errors like this:

```
==10898== Invalid read of size 1
==10898==    at 0x402D4F1: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==10898==    by 0x804AEFB: dir_getDirFromBSON (dir.c:33)
==10898==    by 0x804A4DB: mongo_dir_getByNameInDir (mongo_dir.c:75)
==10898==    by 0x8049601: resolveDir (console.c:192)
==10898==    by 0x8049A3F: changeDir (console.c:322)
==10898==    by 0x804917D: startConsole (console.c:82)
==10898==    by 0x804AFEB: main (main.c:26)
==10898==  Address 0x4289985 is 101 bytes inside a block of size 1,024 free'd
==10898==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==10898==    by 0x40665F9: bson_realloc (in /usr/local/lib/libbson-1.0.so.0.0.0)
==10898==    by 0x4066632: bson_realloc_ctx (in /usr/local/lib/libbson-1.0.so.0.0.0)
==10898==    by 0x4083C98: _mongoc_buffer_destroy (in /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0.0.0)
==10898==    by 0x408EF15: _mongoc_cursor_destroy (in /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0.0.0)
==10898==    by 0x408F044: mongoc_cursor_destroy (in /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0.0.0)
==10898==    by 0x804A190: mongo_getDocByQuery (mongo.c:99)
==10898==    by 0x804A4C7: mongo_dir_getByNameInDir (mongo_dir.c:73)
==10898==    by 0x8049601: resolveDir (console.c:192)
==10898==    by 0x8049A3F: changeDir (console.c:322)
==10898==    by 0x804917D: startConsole (console.c:82)
==10898==    by 0x804AFEB: main (main.c:26)
```

The line 33 shown there is this one:

```
strcpy(dir->parentId, value->value.v_utf8.str);
```

And there are lots of errores in the other lines that read the other strings.

The "deserialization" is done perfectly, but that errors are annoying me and I think that I may be reading the strings in a bad way.

The questions are:

Is there a better way to do this? 
Am I doing something wrong here? 
Why are these errors thrown by valgrind? 
Should I iterate over all the keys or is there any way to get a value from a key?

Comment: `strcpy()` with a fixed size destination buffer is a really bad idea! It may work in most cases, but it will fail on some data... (and will open doors to classic buffer overflow security vurnerabilities).

Comment: So what do you suggest? To get the size and do the malloc inside there before the strcpy()?

Comment: Exactly - it should be easily done in your case.

Comment: For simplicity, you may just remove all `malloc()`s, then make your id also a `char*` instead of `char[25]` and then use `strdup()` instead of `strcpy()`. But then, make sure to also respect your deallocations.